# Jquery, window automatically scrolls down when browser refreshed

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I set a div to the height and width of the window so it looks like a "home screen" and then you can scroll down to see the content and it works fine, but when the browser is refreshed it automatically scrolls down to the point where you were before refreshing but I want it to be at "0" point on the document, any idea what is going on?

here is my code:

```
            <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <style>
    html,body,p,h1,h2,div,section,img{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;

    }
    html,body{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    }
    header{
    background-color:rgba(181,255,0,0.51);
    width:100%;
    /* flex container */
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row no-wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    section{
        text-align:center;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <header></header>
    <section>
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </section>

    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                console.log($(window).scrollTop());
                });

            //screen size
            var windowh = $(window).height();
            var windoww = $(window).width();
            //header full screen
            console.log(windowh + ' '+windoww);
            $('header').css({
                'height': windowh,  
            });

        });





    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't know if that's the case, but this could happen in ASP.NET when the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack property is set to true https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with cache or cookies but I believe this might keep the website from doing that...

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
        $('html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1);
        $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1);
    });
```